# Assigning parent to image stored in Image Array

Tags: c#, image, transparency, parent

I am storing images in an Array, which I am going to display on top of each other (using transparency) in an image box, but how do I set the parent of each image (to enable transparency)?

Is it something along the lines of

```
images[1].parent = images[0];
```

Note, the above code does not work hence the question.

Comment: What's `images`? An array of what? Is this winforms? WPF? Web? Something else?

Comment: Sorry, the images taken locally so i populate the array when the form first loads: 
   `images[0] = Image.FromFile(""+ Application.StartupPath +"../../../images/imageA.png");` 

Its using winforms

Comment: Well then `System.Drawing.Image` doesn't have a `Parent` property of anything similar. If you want to be able to store some meta data with your image you might want to wrap it in a class with a `Parent` property and an `Image` property that contains your actual image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap you images in a class with the property or properties you need (Bitmap is sealed, so you can't just inherit from it):

```
public class MyImageWrapper 
{
    public MyImageWrapper Parent { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }

    public MyImageWrapper(Image i, MyImageWrapper parent = null)
    {
        Parent = parent;
        Image = i;
    }
}
```

Now you can change your array of `Image` to an array `MyImageWrapper` and you can do things like this:

```
Images[1].Parent = Images[0]
```

Of course, you need to remember to access the wrapped image before you try and assign it to a control that expects an Image, for example:

```
pictureBox1.Image = Images[0].Image;
```

And to originally load your images, you would:

```
images[0] = new ImageWrapper(Image.FromFile("MyImage.png"));
```

Comment: I am attempting to use imageWrapper now and have encountered an error when trying to do: `pictureBox1.Image = imageArray[0]; ` - You mentioned I need to access the wrapped image before assigning it, how exactly would I do that. Thanks for your help this is a brilliant answer!

Comment: @user3178614: See my latest edit to clarify. You just need to add `.Image` to the end of your statement.